# How to take means of each row in R if data is of character or factor type?

Tags: r

```
firstset <- read.csv("~/Desktop/firstset.csv", comment.char="#")
secondset <- read.csv("~/Desktop/secondset.csv", comment.char="#")
```

`mrna.c.1 <- data.frame(firstset[3:161, 4:9])`

I want to find the mean of each row contained in in data.frame "mrna.c.1" and store it in a vector called "means.mc1"

I tried using

```
means.mc1 <- apply(mrna.c.1, 1, mean)
```

and

```
means.mc1 <- rowMeans(mrna.c.1)
```

but I think that neither work because my data is not numeric.

What is the best way to convert my data into numeric (or to otherwise calculate the mean of each row)?

Comment: Try the following code `mrna.c.1[] <- sapply(mrna.c.1, as.numeric)`

Comment: `read.csv` converts strings to factors. Use `read.table` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, then you can use any method from that question to convert from character to numeric. Note that you cannot go from `factor` to `numeric` without converting to `character` first

Comment: Is it possible to convert all your columns to numeric type? Do you have any strings/character columns? If yes do you want to exclude them from the `mean` calculation?

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)

iris[1:10,] %>%                                 # example data
  mutate_all(~as.numeric(as.character(.))) %>%  # convert all columns to numeric
  rowMeans(na.rm = T)                           # get row means as a vector

# [1] 2.550 2.375 2.350 2.350 2.550 2.850 2.425 2.525 2.225 2.400
```

The function `~as.numeric(as.character(.))` will keep `numeric` columns as `numeric`, will return `NA` for `character` columns and for `factor` columns with `character` elements.

Or in base R:

`rowMeans(sapply(iris[1:10,], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), na.rm = T)`