# How can I create a row in a data frame that is the sum of other rows in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, plyr

I'm working with a data frame that I extracted from a csv file and trying to make a row that is the sum of many other rows.

I've tried using colSums, numcolwise, and many other functions, but I keep getting all sort of errors.  When using colSums, I get an error that says that I cannot use the colSums function because my data frame is not numeric.

So,

1. How do I make all of the numeric values in the data frame read as numeric? and
2. How do I make a row that adds up all of the rows that apply?

Comment: Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(dataset, 20))`, where `dataset` is the name of your data frame.

Comment: If your data is not numeric, it is not reasonable to expect to sum it up. You can see which columns are causing your problem by typing `sapply(df, class)`   (where df is replaced with the name of your data frame).

Comment: My answer here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903883/how-to-take-means-of-each-row-in-r-if-data-is-of-character-or-factor-type/51903977#51903977 You can use `rowSums` instead of `rowMeans`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `is.numeric` to identify the column numeric columns and filter out non-numeric variables/columns. Please see the example below:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = letters[1:10],
  b = 1:10,
  c = (1:10) / 100,
  d = (1:10) / 50
)

str(df)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: Factor w/ 10 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ b: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#  $ c: num  0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.1
#  $ d: num  0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.1 0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.2

df_nums <- df[, sapply(df, is.numeric)]
str(df_nums)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ b: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ c: num  0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08 0.09 0.1
# $ d: num  0.02 0.04 0.06 0.08 0.1 0.12 0.14 0.16 0.18 0.2

rowSums(df_nums)
# [1]  1.01  2.02  3.03  4.04  5.05  6.06  7.07  8.08  9.09 10.10
```